# Change position of plus and minus buttons google maps apiv2 Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to change position of plus and minus buttons in Google maps form. Is this possible, any ideas how to do that?

Comment: It cannot be changed, but you can remove it and add your own zoom in and out buttons.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this is currently is not possible. The only thing you can configure with the zoom control is whether they are displayed and whether you can use zoom gestures.

Take a look at this documentation :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings

The methods that are related to zoom controls are:

```
public void setZoomGesturesEnabled

public void setZoomControlsEnabled
```

To set Gestures and controls state, and:

```
public boolean isZoomControlsEnabled

public boolean isZoomGesturesEnabled
```

To get their state.

Comment: The link you provided doesn't seem to have information about setZoomGesturesEnabled.

Comment: @AndrewSwift, why not? https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings.html#setZoomGesturesEnabled(boolean)

Comment: Now it seems to be fine -- not sure why I couldn't find it on the page yesterday.